what locale does grep use if no environment variable explicitly sets it?
In case this is relevant: I'm using Git Bash for Windows but NOT the usual mintty launcher (I'm running bash directly), so I have fewer environment variables set than "normal".  In particular, I do not have LC_CTYPE set, which I "normally" would if I were using that launcher.
When I try to run grep -P whatever grep complains that "grep: -P supports only unibyte and UTF-8 locales".  Okay, fair.  But what locale does it THINK that I have?  Let's ask locale.exe what it thinks:
$ locale --version  # check version for sanity
locale (cygwin) 3.4.10
$ locale
locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

I think I saw in some docs that stuff in "quotes" means that this is a fallback value that locale figured out, rather than something it got directly from the environment... this seems to not be true for the Cygwin version, which prints the above in quotes no matter what I try.
But anyway,  C.UTF-8 sure SOUNDS like it should be a UTF-8 locale.  And indeed, if I use LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8 grep -P, then that works fine!  So that means that grep has its own ideas about how to figure out what the default locale is.  So what ARE those ideas?

In a command window or windows terminal, enter the CHCP command to see the current code page, and systeminfo and look at the System Locale: and Input Locale: lines to see what windows things about the locale. This will be inherited by bash.

I see "Active code page: 437" which is certainly a "unibyte" code page... systeminfo reports that my system and input locales are both en-us.  None of this seems to explain the error message.

On my system, in a windows terminal (WT), chcp reports: Active code page: 65001. Also, set lang shows LANG=en_CA.UTF-8. locale reports LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8", so it is inheriting from the LANG setting. I don't use Git Bash anymore, I use MingW64 or CYGWIN instead, with global and local git settings adjusted to match the repository. With CYGWIN it is essential to use CYGWIN's bash. With MingW64, you can run some git commands directly from the WT, but bash is recommended.

Any idea how to find out what on earth grep is doing without stepping through grep in a debugger?  It's more curiosity than practicality at this point but it feels so weird.

You can download the source package for grep using the official installer. There is a check box under the heading Src?. In an elevated bash window run chown -R USER:USER /usr/src/grep-3.11-1.src/ where USER is your cygwin user id. Then, in non-elevated shell, run cd /usr/src/grep-3.11-1.src, and then cygport grep.cygport download prep. You will find the grep source in grep-3.11-1.x86_64/src/grep-3.11/. cd there and use grep -R "= \?getenv" . to find which environment variables grep uses, and examine the c code to see how they are used. HTH

That might not be trivial... for example, it might NEVER call getenv directly, and instead call setlocale with an empty string, and let that call getenv on its behalf.

grep does in fact call getenv numerous times for several env vars. You can use a similar grep command to find all the setlocale calls too, but do the getenv calls first!

I asked on the mailing list... it turns out that grep does indeed just do the "boring" thing and calls setlocale with the empty string... interestingly, I can only replicate this when using the Git for Windows grep (tried two computers just in case) ... if I try msys2 on the same computer, that works fine.  so this must be specific to how that project implemented locales.
